# LiveData observer not removed after removing

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

I am observing  a list of objects in `LiveData` I have removed the observers manually but the it is not removed. It is getting called again after a change. Here is the code. Here `repo.`getKeyFor' returns `LiveData<List<ImageAddress>>` against the arguments passed. ImageAddress is the class I created.

```
 repo.getKeyFor(fname).observe(this, new Observer<List<ImageAddress>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ImageAddress> imageAddresses) {
                try{
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: decrpted Image inside :"+fname);
                ImageAddress imageAddress=imageAddresses.get(0);
                String strKey=imageAddress.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: IMAGE address:"+imageAddresses.get(0).getAddress()+", "+imageAddress.getKey());
                SecretKey k=convertKey(strKey);
                byte[] decryptedImgArray=cryptoChaCha20.decrypt(imgArr,k);
                String decFile=getChangedFileName(rawFilePath,"Decrypted");
                saveFile(decFile,decryptedImgArray);

                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: decrpted Image inside :"+fname);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Decrypted! Saved to gallery!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(isImageFile(decFile)){
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedImgArray , 0, decryptedImgArray.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); }

                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    finish();
                }
                finally{
                repo.getKeyFor(fname).removeObservers(MainActivity.this);}
            }
        });
```

code for getKeyFor()

```
 LiveData<List<ImageAddress>> getKeyFor(String address){ return dao.getKeyFor(address);}
```

Comment: Where is "getKeyFor()" code? It could spawn a new LiveData instance at each call, so we need to see it. And: THIS of "observe(this, ...)" is the same of "MainActivity.this"?

Comment: @emandt I added the code. Kindly check

Comment: Try to save LiveData (returned by getKeyFor) to a variable, and then call removeObservers on that variable.
Assuming that dao is genereted by room, the method getKeyFor will return a new instance of LiveData in each call.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't help. Your "getKeyFor()"is just a "passthrough" method for "dao.getKeyFor()" and I don't know what it does under the hood. Try to run in Debug mode and set a Breakpoint at each "repo.getKeyFor(fname)" call, then evaluate it by selecting it and pressing ALT+F8. Check if "@123456" value is the same for all evaluations.

Comment: @PauloPereira Thank you so much! That was the issue. I added a condition in 'getKeyFor()' which will call 'dao.getKeyFor()' only if the 'LiveData' object(which I defined) is null.

Comment: @PauloPereira add your answer so I can mark it correct. That may help others too :)

Comment: It's good way to fix it. 
I advise you to take a look at ViewModel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel. Could help you on future changes.

Also the method https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E) could be helpful to you if you are trying to update a view just if the value on database changes.

Happy to help.

Comment: Second thought on your solution.
Is my understanding that you want onChanged to be called just once by each time you call getKeyFor().observe. If that the case i advise you to seek for another solution.

Comment: @PauloPereira Yeah I know about view model but since I didn't want to preserve the data so I didn't use it. Yeah you are right I want onChanged() to be called just once for each call for getKeyFor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save LiveData (returned by getKeyFor) to a variable
2. Then call removeObservers on that variable

Note: Assuming that dao is genereted by room, the method getKeyFor will return a new instance of LiveData in each call.